# Swift 2.0 Callback Syntax: What is $0?

Tags: swift2

I am updating to Swift 2.0.

My old code:

```
animateButtonsOnScreen(callback: completedImageEditingButtonSwap)
```

The new code the compiler wants:

```
animateButtonsOnScreen(callback: { completedImageEditingButtonSwap($0) })
```

`callback:` has no params. What is this new $0 object? I don't have params so what is it trying to reference here?

NB: the compiler says this where I wants me to use this new syntax

> Use a closure to safely wrap calls to the function

**Update with some code**

```
func swapButtonsForImageCapture()
{

    if(DeviceProperties.isIphone4() == true)//iPhone 4s needs smaller icon
    {
        _takePhotoButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "snapimageicon4s"), forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    }else
    {
        _takePhotoButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "snapimageicon"), forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    }
    _takePhotoButton.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.AllEvents)
    _takePhotoButton.addTarget(_controller, action: Selector("takePhoto:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    let buttonsToAnimateOut:[UIButton] = [_textButton,_filtersButton,_previewButton]
    animateButtonsOffScreen(buttonsToAnimateOut, callback: { self.swapButtonsForImageCapturePart2($0) })
}

func swapButtonsForImageCapturePart2()
{
    let buttonsToAnimateIn:[UIButton] = [_swapCameraButton,_flashButton,_galleryButton]
    animateButtonsOnScreen(buttonsToAnimateIn, callback: { self.completedImageCaptureButtonSwap($0) })
}
```

Comment: Can be a compiler bug. `$0` is the first argument to the closure, but like you said, your function doesn't take any param.

Comment: Of course. I've only had to update my entire code base 3 times now. Why would I think the compiler has made its mind haha!

Comment: Could you provide a bit more code to look at?

Comment: Uhhh what specifically? Its just an empty param function call.

Comment: Maybe some playground example where this also happens? This would help, I want to understand why this is happening here, it seems strange to me as well.

Comment: I added some code but I don't think it will illuminate anything helpful.

Comment: Can you show the definition of `completedImageEditingButtonSwap`?

Comment: Theres nothing in there of relevance, trust me

Comment: Sorry it is almost the same code as before, you should provide how `animateButtonsOnScreen`, `completedImageCaptureButtonSwap` , `swapButtonsForImageCapturePart2` functions are implemented (I mean not the inner mechanics but the structure of the functions itself, return type etc.) ... Lets take a look at `callback: { self.completedImageCaptureButtonSwap($0) }`. Is by any chance the `self` inside that closure not an instance but a type? If then you are calling a `normal function` and not a `class/static function` you will be forced by the compiler to provide one argument.

Comment: Lets say you have two functions `func foo() { self.dynamicType.boo(/*needs an argument*/)  }` and `func boo()`. This will return the function `boo()` but not execute it right away.

Comment: Yea there's not static, theres just the one function. Right now, Xcode is too unstable  I think. I constantly lose syntax highlighting as soon as I type, and the compiler is beyond confused. Theres over 200 issues, I think I am going to ice this problem and wait for the next beta/stable release.